# ORA-15045: ASM file name '+DATA' is not in reference form

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed standalone database with oracle ASM. Installation and database creation and all are completed successfully.But,When I restarted the database,I got the below error and when I checked the alert log where I saw the error like 'ORA-15045: ASM file name '+DATA' is not in reference form'.Please provide me any solution and let me know if you need any other data.

```
SQL> startup 
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  521936896 bytes
Fixed Size          2214936 bytes
Variable Size         314573800 bytes
Database Buffers      201326592 bytes
Redo Buffers            3821568 bytes

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info

My alert log shows errors as below.

Fri Sep 15 14:59:56 2017
ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
ORA-00202: control file: '+DATA'
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +DATA
ORA-15045: ASM file name '+DATA' is not in reference form
ORA-205 signalled during: alter database mount...

Please see the below permissions for oracle and grid

[oracle@standalone disks]$ ls -lrt /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle
-rwsr-s--x 1 oracle asmadmin 210823892 Sep 13 20:11 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle

uid=54321(oracle) gid=54321(oinstall) groups=54321(oinstall),54322(dba),54323(asmadmin),54324(asmdba),54326(oper)
[oracle@standalone disks]$ id grid
uid=54322(grid) gid=54323(asmadmin) groups=54323(asmadmin),54321(oinstall),54322(dba),54324(asmdba),54325(asmoper)
[oracle@standalone disks]$
```

Comment: No one has given reply to my question.Can any one help on this.